# What's the best way to store App Data on OSX on a Contacts like App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm making a Contacts like App with the following data:

- Contact Name
- Contact Info
- Contact Emails (protected by a password, and this password is part of the Data)
  etc...

I need this information at Application startup, and I've searched around and I found out Core Data. But I don't need Core Data versions, or files, no need to undo/redo, etc... I just need this data "inside" the App. At first I thought about NSUserDefaults, but I'm not sure about that.
How should I save this data?

Comment: Core Data is definitely the way to go for something like this. NSUserDefaults is not. Saving the data to a documents file is okay too, but Core Data should be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is the best approach in my opponion because it's the most flexible. You could alternatively store the objects in an array and write that out to a file - though not as elegant it should work for a contact like app (since its unlikely that there will be thousands of contacts to manage).

Comment: do u know any good tutorials out there for core data? i can only find core data document-based...

Comment: iTunes U, iOS development fall 2011, paul hegarty. There is core data coverage